# Filter list of phone numbers using php

Tags: php, regex

I have a list of phone numbers that start with the below numbers and in different formats...i need to grab the numbers that start only with the below numbers/format using php......

```
020 8
07974 
+44 (0) 20
+44 0
440203
```

any help will be appreciated..

Comment: So you don't really want to sort, you want to match/filter?

Comment: Could you please show us what you have got now (part of the phone list as it is), and what you want it to be after you're done with it.

@Gordon & some other person : Thanks for the upvotes :)

Answer (score 3):

```
/^(020 8|07974|\+44 \(0\) 20|\+44 0|440203).*/

if(preg_match("/^(020 8|07974|\+44 \(0\) 20|\+44 0|440203).*/",  $numbers[i])
  echo i + "th number is valid";
```